# Sending EOS pipeline gstreamer

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, command-line-arguments, gstreamer

I have an example gstreamer pipeline: `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! image/jpeg,width=1280, height=800, framerate=30/1 ! v4l2jpegdec ! queue ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls="controls, h264_profile=4, video_bitrate=620000" ! 'video/x-h264, profile=high, level=(string)4' ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=output2.mkv`

That I run it from the command line. Instead of doing ctrl+c to kill the process, I want to send an EOS event to the process.

Is this possible? And if so, has anyone done it or what is the solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [it has been cross-posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75377507/10765659) and answered there. [Cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do do this but I added `watchdog timeout=1000` to the pipe and disconnected the video input, then the watchdog terminates the stream and generates the EOS. I also have a `-e` at the end of my command to ensure that the video file is properly closed:

```
 gst-launch-1.0.exe rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.189.3:8554/bandwidth_h264 latency=0 ! decodebin ! watchdog timeout=1000 ! tee name=split split.! queue leaky=1 ! autovideosink sync=false split.! queue leaky=1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=c:/demo/test.mp4 -e
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).